# Calculate cosine similarity between 2 words using BERT

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, word-embedding, cosine-similarity

I am trying to calculate the cosine similarity beteween two given words using BERT, but I am getting an error which says:

```
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

in the line :

```
similarity = torch.cosine_similarity(word1_embedding, word2_embedding)
```

below you find the code I am using until now, does someone have an idea what the problem could be?

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
import torch

# Load the BERT model and tokenizer
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

# Tokenize the input words
word1 = "cat"
word2 = "dog"
input_ids = torch.tensor([tokenizer.encode(word1, word2, add_special_tokens=True)])

# Get the BERT embeddings for the input words
output = model(input_ids)[0]

# Get the first and second word embeddings
word1_embedding = output[0, 1, :]
word2_embedding = output[0, 2, :]

# Calculate the cosine similarity between the two words
similarity = torch.cosine_similarity(word1_embedding, word2_embedding)
print(similarity)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your tokenizer and the output indexing for inputting to the `cosine_similarity`.

*If we change `word2` from `dog` to `cat` we get the output of `cosine_similarity` like this: `tensor([1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)`*

```
# !pip install transformers
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
import torch

# Load the BERT model and tokenizer
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

# Tokenize the input words
word1 = "cat"
word2 = "dog"
input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer([word1, word2], add_special_tokens=True)['input_ids'])

# Get the BERT embeddings for the input words
output = model(input_ids)[0]

# Get the first and second word embeddings
word1_embedding = output[0]
word2_embedding = output[1]

# Calculate the cosine similarity between the two words
similarity = torch.cosine_similarity(word1_embedding, word2_embedding)

print(similarity)
# tensor([0.9665, 0.7953, 0.9809], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
```

Comment: Hi I'mahdi thank you very much for helping me with this, but i still have one question isn't the cosine similarity supposed to be a value between -1 and 1 ? if yes how can extract it from the result tensor ?